# NiFi how to release flow file until a process downstream is finished

Tags: apache-nifi

I am designing a data ingestion pattern using NiFi. One process needs to stop releasing flow files until a process downstream has finished processed. I tried to use wait and notified and have not made any success. I am hoping if the queue size and back pressure can be set across a few processors.

Similarly if there's a way I can implement logic: Don't allow flow files go in if there is one currently processing between multiple processors.

Any help is appreciated 
[image: Flow diagram]

Comment: Use one flowfile and if it is finished, then redirect that flowfile to the data cleansing again with modified attributes by `UpdateAttribute` processor. In your case, you do not need the new flowfile.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus I have taken your suggestion to design the solution below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to design a solution within NiFi. Essentially using generate flow file as a signal (Only run once ever). The trick is have the newly generated flow file to merge with the original input flow through defragmentation. And every time after the flow has finished, the success condition will be able to merge with the next input flow file.

[Solution Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlC7x.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of MonitorActivity with executestreamcommand (with a python "nipyapi" script).

I have a similar requirement in one of my working flows.

[image]

You will need to install python lib nipyapi first and create this script on the nifi box.

```
from time import sleep
import nipyapi

nipyapi.utils.set_endpoint('http://ipaddress:port/nifi-api', ssl=False, login=False)
## Get PG ID using the PG Name
mypg = nipyapi.canvas.get_process_group('start')
nipyapi.canvas.schedule_process_group(mypg.id, scheduled=True) ## Start
sleep(1)
nipyapi.canvas.schedule_process_group(mypg.id, scheduled=False) ## Stop
```

I will put the template in the img in the link bellow, see the configuration on the monitor-activity processor - it will generate a flow if not activity is happening for 10 sec(you can play with the times thou).
[Download template](https://gofile.io/?c=4tgEMT)

**Note:** this is not a very good approach if you have high latency requirements.

Another idea would be to monitor the aggregate queue in the entire flow and if queue is zero then you restart start flow. (this would be very intense if you have a lot of connections)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The cluster we are using does not allow developers to run code outside of NiFi UI. Thus we cannot create a script to run outside of NiFi.