# How do I only release the next csv file in the GetFile processor queue in NiFi 1.23 until the last processor downstream has finished

Tags: apache-nifi

I have developed a data ingestion Flow that processes identically formatted csv files using NiFi 1.23.2. The issue is that I only want to release the next csv file in the directory specified in the GetFile processor, if the previous csv file has finished processing the last processor downstream, or the process fails and is routed to a LogMessage processor on Failure, without having to create a script to run outside of NiFi. I have tried using wait and notified but I have not had any success.

I have tried to design a NiFi processor loop construct, but that only works when the process makes it to the last processor without failure. On Failure I want to signal the GetFile and release next csv file. I have tried Wait/Notify without much success.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that the GetFile Processor [documentation][1] states, "This component does not allow an incoming relationship." Therefore, anything that it is unable to receive instructions to run from an external processor, as only the settings in the processor will handle how often GetFile runs. What I am saying is that GetFile is the start of a process and wont be able to receive any notifications to do something unless its explicitly specified in the GetFile Processor.

I am unsure of how your system works and the details, but what you could do is have GetFile point to directory B. If the initial data is sent to directory A, what you could do is have the relationship be routed to another processor that would move the next file from directory A to B so the GetFile Processor can be triggered.

Note, this is just 1 option that one could take.
[1]: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/index.html

Comment: My Apologies my scenario wasn't clear. The GetFile processor is pulling multiple files from a directory. So let's say that there are 3 Flowfiles in the directory. When the GetFIle processor passes those files to the next processor group in the flow, I would like to hold two of those files queued and send only one to the next processor group. After that file exits that next processor group, then I want to release the second of the three files, and so on.

Comment: I attempted to replicate the solution flow here, but I haven't got the Flow working yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186162/nifi-how-to-release-flow-file-until-a-process-downstream-is-finished   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlC7x.png